# Finding the sum of n terms $S_n$ starting from sigma $k=0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} ((4k-3)\cdot 2^k)+4=(2^{n+3}+4)n-7\cdot2^{n+1}+15$$

How? I've tried everything but i don't see it. Any equivalent solutions are also welcome, thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell if know $k$'s and $n$'s are correct?

Comment: Yeah. The $S_n$ output should be: $n(1) = 7, n(2) = 32, n(3) = 107....$ since $(4k-3)*2^k)+4$ since 1,6, 24, 76, 212,....

Comment: Ok, thanks because I edited the question and I was not sure.

Comment: The $+4$ is inside the summation, right?

Comment: @sayantan yeah, it shouldn't change much if omitted I think. Just the last term of $S_n$ will be 11. So 11+4 = 15 as above.

Comment: Yeah. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this important geometric sum :

**Lemma 1** 
$$A(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k=2^{n+1}-1$$

We'll now find another sum :

**Lemma 2**

$$B(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k 2^k$$

To find this sum simply break it in sums you already know from Lemma 1 like this :

$$B(n)=0+1 \cdot 2^1+2 \cdot 2^2+\ldots n \cdot 2^n=(2^1+2^2+\ldots +2^n)+(2^2+2^3+\ldots +2^n)+\ldots+(2^n)=2A(n-1)+2^2A(n-2)+\ldots +2^nA(0)=2(2^n-1)+2^2(2^{n-1}-1)+\ldots +(2^{n+1}-2^n)=n2^{n+1}-(2+2^2+\ldots+2^n)=n2^{n+1}-(2^{n+1}-2)=(n-1)2^{n+1}+2$$

Now your sum is just $$4B(n)-3A(n)+4(n+1)$$ which you can find by plugging in from Lemma 1 and 2.

Comment: Um so $4(2^{n+1}-1)-3((n-1)2^{n+1}+2)+4$ ?

Comment: @Mathy You interchanged $A(n)$ and $B(n)$ . It should be $$4((n-1)2^{n+1}+2)-3(2^{n+1}-1)+4$$

Comment: Oh ops, thanks :) so tried to find the values.. and it gives me $n(1)=3, n(2)=23, n(3) = 95...$ not $n(1)=7,n(2)=31,n(3)=107$.... since $(4k−3)∗2k)+4$  = 1,6, 24, 76, 212,....

Comment: @Mathy I know what's the problem .There is a $4$ in every term of the sum so I should have written instead $$4B(n)-3A(n)+4n$$ (I thought there's a single $4$ for the entire sum :)) ) . Silly mistake .

Comment: Haha yeah! It's alright. Could you also update your answer? :) thanks again

Comment: so it should be $4((n−1)2^{n+1}+2)−3(2^{n+1}−1)+4(n+1)$ right? and are the steps toward this solution the same? just add "4(n+1)" right?

Comment: @Mathy Yes just add $4(n+1)$

Comment: Thanks so much!! I'm really trying to learn this and you've helped me :)))

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \{((4k-3)\cdot 2^k)+4\}$$
$$=-3(2^{n+1}-1)+4(2^{n+1}-2)+...+4(2^{n+1}-2^n)$$
$$=-3(2^{n+1}-1)+n \cdot 4 \cdot 2^{n+1}-4(2^{n+1}-2)+4(n+1)$$
$$=(2^{n+3}+4)n-7\cdot2^{n+1}+15$$

Comment: Wonderful. Is this the only way you would have solved this? Let's say you were given just $\sum_{k=0}^{n} ((4k-3)\cdot 2^k)+4$. How you would do it? I mean I'm sure they are other equivalent solutions

Comment: @Mathy Umm... Hard to say... I particularly like number theory... So, I would've approached it in this very way I believe as it consists of summation of consecutive powers of two... But, there are other ways, as Stef and Aretino have mentioned... But, I'm a High School student... This is the best for me... :P

Comment: Ahh! Gotcha. Thanks though. I appreciated though :) keep it up

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit a telescoping sum:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\bigl((k+1)2^{k+1}-k2^k\bigr)=(n+1)2^{n+1},
$$
because you also have:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\bigl((k+1)2^{k+1}-k2^k\bigr)=
\sum_{k=0}^n\bigl(k2^k-2^{k+1}\bigr)
$$
so that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n  k2^k=
\sum_{k=0}^n\bigl((k+1)2^{k+1}-k2^k\bigr)+\sum_{k=0}^n2^{k+1}
=(n+1)2^{n+1}+2(2^{n+1}-1)
$$

Comment: Aretino, thanks for the input. Is the "telescopic summation" method calculus? Just looked it up and linked me to a straight calculus page

Comment: No, it is not: it simply refers to a sum where all terms vanish, except the first and last ones, e.g. $\sum_{k=1}^n[(k+1)^2-k^2]=(n+1)^2-1^2$.

Comment: See also here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html

Comment: Great, thanks. So is this just a demonstration of how the "telescopic summation" works?

Comment: It is an example where it can be useful. You can do a lot of things with telescoping sums, as for instance to find recursive formulas for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^m$, when $m$ is a positive integer.